# How to make update query when user status changed to 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i got issue while if statement running. i want to update query on those user_id's who status changed from 0 to 1. but this query run on all status userid who already 1. but i want run on those who changed to 0 to 1. and run only one time don't many time. please help me to solve this. Thanks

```
if($status==1) 
 {
   $query22= "UPDATE `user` SET `global` =$row[user_id] WHERE 
             `user_id` = '".$_SESSION['userid']."' ";

   $current_id = $db_handle->insertquery($query22); 
 }
```

Comment: The least you could do is format your code. Also, you wish to do an `UPDATE` but the function is `insertquery`? Either that is terrible naming or that is your issue.

Comment: Hello @Script47 i just want on if statement when status 0 to 1 change.

Comment: You never read my comment. Please reread it.

Comment: okay i update it on updatequery but then same work. @Script47

Comment: how exactly did their status change?

Comment: You need to show us the code that queries the $status and explain how and when the status is changing. $status is just a variable that holds a currently queried status I presume and there's no way to just fix your if statement if you don't carry or persist the information about status history.

Comment: Hello @Jarek.D i made like this one but nothing help?? :-

 if  ($status == (0 > 1) ) {
//then update query
}

But nothing help :(

Comment: This is not how you do it. We can help only if you start reading the suggestions here, trying to understand them and providing requested information.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below condition:

```
 if($status=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to take some action when a status is changed by user, Ignore answer if thats not the case.

First you need to check the initial status. This you most probably need to fetch from database.

Lets call this variable $initialStatus

```
$initialStatus = fetchUserStatus($userId); // need to implement fetchUserStatus
```

then you can put your check something like this,

```
if($status==1 && $initialStatus==0){
// do some action
}
```